# Does a Faraday Cage need to be sealed to block RF?

Tags: radio-frequency

I was watching a program on shoplifting and there were things called booster bags shown, which blocked a security tag which acts as an LC resonator when put between the security towers, causes the alarm to go off. The bags were made of tin foil but open at the top. They act as faraday cage blocking the RF from reaching the tag but if its open at the top then how are they still able to block it?

Answer (score 2):

Since the RF gate uses rather low frequency, the bag is much smaller than the wavelenght of the corresponding radio wave. It is also quite easy to get near "perfect conductor" at sub-MHz frequencies.

This means the field strength decays exponentially with the depth of the open bag, and the exponential decay is the faster, the narrower the bag is. (More exact approach is to investigate the solutions of Poisson equation in partially open cavity, but the previously written rule should hold unless the geometry gets complex enough to support resonances.) In short, it is the geometry of the narrow bag that strongly reduces the RF field.

Comment: Are you saying it redirects the field up and away from the towers?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn No, I don't think that.